# c++ share HINTERNET between functions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a global HINTERNET for some functions, which need an internet-handle.

my code is like that:

```
static HINTERNET hInternetConnection = NULL;

void connectToInternet()
{
    HINTERNET hInternetOpen = InternetOpen(
        "CustomAgent",              // Agent
        INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,  // AccessType
        NULL,                       // ProxyName
        NULL,                       // ProxyBypass
        0                           // Flags
        );
    if (GetLastError() != 0)
        return;

    hInternetConnection = InternetConnect(
        hInternetOpen,              // InternetOpen-Handle
        "http://www.example.com",   // ServerName
        INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, // ServerPort
        NULL,                       // Username
        NULL,                       // Password
        INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,      // Service
        0,                          // Flags
        0                           // Context
        );
}

void useInternetConnection()
{
    HINTERNET httpOpenRequest = HttpOpenRequest(
        hInternetConnection,    // Internet-Handle
        "GET",                  // HTTP-Verb
        "/test.php",    // request target
        "HTTP/1.1",             // HTTP-Version
        NULL,
        NULL,
        INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,
        0
        );
    if (GetLastError() != 0)
        cout << "ERROR: " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
```

but for my second function `useInternetConnection()` I recieve Error Code 6 `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

So isn't it possible to use one global HINTERNET for functions? How could I avoid this situation?
Would it be better if I would change the return type of the first function to a HINTERNET, and call this function from any other function where I need a Handle?

The primary idea for me doing this were some internet-connection-problems with a toughbook-modem. I ran a few programs - partially simultaneously, partially seperate - and it seams that randomly the modem crashes and the internet connection was absent for some time (seconds to hours).
Now I tried to wrap all previous programs into functions of one big program and to share one internet-handle to some of these functions, but it don't seems to work... The reason why I don't try to solve my problem like my previous idea by changing the return-type of `connectToInternet()` is that I'm afraid that this could cause the same problem like running multiple applications - all trying to access the internet...

Any ideas?

Comment: What you want to achieve is possible. Your real code is supposedly different from the quoted snippet and hence `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

Comment: @RomanR. while writing a statement like "of course my real code is different" i looked over my code again and again and finally found the error! Therefore: thank you very much! I sould just test and debug my code even more, before asking...

Comment: My guess was you had `HINTERNET hInternetConnection = InternetConnect(...` instead of `hInternetConnection = InternetConnect(...` in your real code. Anyway, great news you fixed it and you can move on now.

Comment: haha, no ;-) I had `return` at first in my `connectToInternet` function, if `InternetGetConnectedState(NULL, NULL);` was true... so there was no call to 'InternetConnect()`